# How to expand a DF creating rows based on the difference of two dates in each row?

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I have a DF with the id, dates of check in and check out of patients and number of days in a hospital. I need a new DF where I have one instance of id for each day between the date a patient checked in and checked out.

```
            id      dt_in     dt_out stay
 4317107984013 2017-11-12 2017-11-28   16    # First row
 4317107984035 2017-11-22 2017-11-29    7    # Second row
 4317107984046 2017-11-18 2017-11-29   11
 4317107984057 2017-11-27 2017-11-29    2
 4317107984079 2017-11-15 2017-11-29   14
 4317107984090 2017-11-19 2017-11-29   10
 4318100215913 2018-01-04 2018-01-04    0
 4317108791611 2017-12-14 2017-12-14    0
 4317107931059 2017-11-23 2017-11-23    0
 4317108756092 2017-11-23 2017-12-27   34
```

I need something like this, for the first 2 rows above

```
           id      dt_in 
4317107984013 2017-11-12   # First row
4317107984013 2017-11-13
4317107984013 2017-11-14
4317107984013 2017-11-15
4317107984013 2017-11-16
4317107984013 2017-11-17
4317107984013 2017-11-17
4317107984013 2017-11-19
4317107984013 2017-11-20
4317107984013 2017-11-21
4317107984013 2017-11-22
4317107984013 2017-11-23
4317107984013 2017-11-24
4317107984013 2017-11-25
4317107984013 2017-11-26
4317107984013 2017-11-27
4317107984013 2017-11-28
4317107984035 2017-11-22   # Second row
4317107984035 2017-11-23
4317107984035 2017-11-24
4317107984035 2017-11-25
4317107984035 2017-11-26
4317107984035 2017-11-27
4317107984035 2017-11-28
4317107984035 2017-11-29
...
```

My system:
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS  10.14.4

```r
# Here is my original DF:

df <- structure(list(id = c("4317107984013", "4317107984035", "4317107984046", 
"4317107984057", "4317107984079", "4317107984090", "4318100215913", 
"4317108791611", "4317107931059", "4317108756092"), dt_in = structure(c(17482, 
17492, 17488, 17497, 17485, 17489, 17535, 17514, 17493, 17493
), class = "Date"), dt_out = structure(c(17498, 17499, 17499, 
17499, 17499, 17499, 17535, 17514, 17493, 17527), class = "Date"), 
    stay = c(16L, 7L, 11L, 2L, 14L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 34L)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
dat%>%
  group_by(id)%>%
  transmute(dt = list(seq(ymd(dt_in),ymd(dt_out),1)))%>%
  unnest()

# A tibble: 104 x 2
# Groups:   id [10]
   id            dt        
   <chr>         <date>    
 1 4317107984013 2017-11-12
 2 4317107984013 2017-11-13
 3 4317107984013 2017-11-14
 4 4317107984013 2017-11-15
 5 4317107984013 2017-11-16
 6 4317107984013 2017-11-17
 7 4317107984013 2017-11-18
 8 4317107984013 2017-11-19
 9 4317107984013 2017-11-20
10 4317107984013 2017-11-21
# ... with 94 more rows
```

Comment: This code worked like a charm in every DF I tested, even large ones. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr` and `tidyr`, you can do:

```
df %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 complete(dt_in = seq.Date(dt_in, dt_out, "day")) %>%
 select(id, dt_in)

   id            dt_in     
   <chr>         <date>    
 1 4317107931059 2017-11-23
 2 4317107984013 2017-11-12
 3 4317107984013 2017-11-13
 4 4317107984013 2017-11-14
 5 4317107984013 2017-11-15
 6 4317107984013 2017-11-16
 7 4317107984013 2017-11-17
 8 4317107984013 2017-11-18
 9 4317107984013 2017-11-19
10 4317107984013 2017-11-20
# … with 94 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. When I used in a large data set (12M rows) had an error. I will post it soon.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `uncount` from `tidyr` -

```
df %>% 
  uncount(stay, .id = "stay") %>% 
  mutate(
    dt_in = as.Date(dt_in) + stay - 1
  ) %>% 
  select(-stay, -dt_out)

# showing results for only 1st id

             id      dt_in
1  4.317108e+12 2017-11-12
2  4.317108e+12 2017-11-13
3  4.317108e+12 2017-11-14
4  4.317108e+12 2017-11-15
5  4.317108e+12 2017-11-16
6  4.317108e+12 2017-11-17
7  4.317108e+12 2017-11-18
8  4.317108e+12 2017-11-19
9  4.317108e+12 2017-11-20
10 4.317108e+12 2017-11-21
11 4.317108e+12 2017-11-22
12 4.317108e+12 2017-11-23
13 4.317108e+12 2017-11-24
14 4.317108e+12 2017-11-25
15 4.317108e+12 2017-11-26
16 4.317108e+12 2017-11-27
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `map2`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  transmute(id, dt_in = map2(dt_in, dt_out, seq, by = '1 day')) %>% 
  unnest
# A tibble: 104 x 2
#   id            dt_in        
#   <chr>         <date>    
# 1 4317107984013 2017-11-12
# 2 4317107984013 2017-11-13
# 3 4317107984013 2017-11-14
# 4 4317107984013 2017-11-15
# 5 4317107984013 2017-11-16
# 6 4317107984013 2017-11-17
# 7 4317107984013 2017-11-18
# 8 4317107984013 2017-11-19
# 9 4317107984013 2017-11-20
#10 4317107984013 2017-11-21
# … with 94 more rows
```

---

Or an option with `base R`

```
lst1 <- Map(seq, df$dt_in, df$dt_out, MoreArgs = list(by = "1 day"))
out <- data.frame(id = rep(df$id, lengths(lst1)), dt_in = do.call(c, lst1))
```